# Postgres CTE : type character varying(255)[] in non-recursive term but type character varying[] overall

Tags: postgresql, graph-theory, common-table-expression

I am new to SO and postgres so please excuse my ignorance. Attempting to get the cluster for a graph in postgres using a solution similar to the one in this post [Find cluster given node in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242672/find-cluster-given-node-in-postgresql)

the only difference is my id is a UUID and I am using varchar(255) to store this id

when i try to run the query I get the following error (but not sure how to cast):

```
ERROR: recursive query "search_graph" column 1 has type character varying(255)[] in non-recursive term but type character varying[] overall
```

SQL state: 42804
    Hint: Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.
Character: 81

my code (basically same as previous post):

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(path, last_profile1, last_profile2) AS (
SELECT ARRAY[id], id, id
FROM node WHERE id = '408d6b12-d03e-42c2-a2a7-066b3c060a0b'
UNION ALL
SELECT sg.path || m.toid || m.fromid, m.fromid, m.toid
FROM search_graph sg
JOIN rel m
ON (m.fromid = sg.last_profile2 AND NOT sg.path @> ARRAY[m.toid]) 
   OR (m.toid = sg.last_profile1 AND NOT sg.path @> ARRAY[m.fromid])
)

 SELECT DISTINCT unnest(path) FROM search_graph;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try casting the `SELECT` lists in the recursive and non-recursive terms to `varchar`.

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(path, last_profile1, last_profile2) AS (
    SELECT ARRAY[id]::varchar[], id::varchar, id::varchar
    FROM node WHERE id = '408d6b12-d03e-42c2-a2a7-066b3c060a0b'
  UNION ALL
    SELECT (sg.path || m.toid || m.fromid)::varchar[], m.fromid::varchar, m.toid::varchar
    FROM search_graph sg
    JOIN rel m
    ON (m.fromid = sg.last_profile2 AND NOT sg.path @> ARRAY[m.toid]) 
       OR (m.toid = sg.last_profile1 AND NOT sg.path @> ARRAY[m.fromid])
)
SELECT DISTINCT unnest(path) FROM search_graph;
```

Comment: on to the next error:
ERROR: operator does not exist: text[] @> character varying[]
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 368

Comment: @todd If you use varchar elsewhere, just cast it all to varchar. Updated. Honestly, In PostgreSQL it's usually better to just use text and if you need a length constraint, add a CHECK constraint. Otherwise, work out where that `varchar(255)` is coming from and fix it to be consistent with the unconstrained varchar used by the rest of your code.

Comment: that worked for me, thanks! I will look into using text... can't upvote due to lack of reputation :(

Comment: @todd You appear to have tried to edit the reply to show use of casts to `varchar(255)[]` instead of `varchar[]`. Is that what you landed up having to use?

Comment: yes, for now, only because the schema is frozen until the next release

Comment: This cast never ever had any effect for me, with PostgreSQL 9.1: `array[guid]::varchar[]` (where `guid` is a `varchar(32)`) — Postgres insisted that *column 3 has type character varying(32)[]* over and over again. However, I was able to fool PostgreSQL into doing the right thing, like so: `array[guid || '']::varchar[]`

Comment: @KajMagnus , no way .. Works for me too, just with NUMERIC - fooling it using array[id+ 0]. Cheers!