# postgresql Convert array type from a non recurcive terme

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a recurcive query and I work on a guid stocked in a varchar(90) column. But I got an cast type exception from pgAdmin when working with Postgres 11.1

I'm stuck and I don't know what could i do to solve this, if any one can help me.

https://docs.postgresql.fr/8.4/queries-with.html

[Postgres CTE : type character varying(255)[] in non-recursive term but type character varying[] overall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488282/postgres-cte-type-character-varying255-in-non-recursive-term-but-type-char/12488455)

```
with recursive sousSujet(typerefin,coderefin,typerefout,coderefout,type,profondeur,chemin, boucle) as (

    SELECT p.typerefin, p.coderefin, p.typerefout , p.coderefout , p.type,1, ARRAY[p.coderefout]::varchar(90)[] ,false  
    FROM relation p
    WHERE p.coderefin='2019094070' and p.typerefin='PROJET'

    --union all     
    union

    SELECT p.typerefin, p.coderefin, pr.typerefout, pr.coderefout, p.type ,pr.profondeur+1,
        --chemin || pr.coderefout,pr.coderefout = ANY(pr.chemin)
        chemin::varchar(90)[] || pr.coderefout,pr.coderefout = ANY(pr.chemin::varchar(90)[])
    FROM relation p,sousSujet pr
    -- WHERE p.coderefin = pr.coderefout    
    WHERE p.coderefin = pr.coderefout AND NOT pr.boucle and pr.profondeur < 10
)
SELECT typerefin,coderefin,typerefout,coderefout,type,profondeur
FROM sousSujet 
order by coderefout limit 20
```

```
ERROR:  ERREUR:  dans la requête récursive « soussujet », la colonne 7 a le type character varying(90)[] dans le terme non
récursif mais le type global character varying[]
LINE 3: ...oderefin, p.typerefout , p.coderefout , p.type,1, ARRAY[p.co...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Convertit la sortie du terme non récursif dans le bon type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error complains that the term

```
ARRAY[p.coderefout]::varchar(90)[]
```

in the non-recursive part has type `varchar(90)[]`, but the corresponding expression

```
chemin::varchar(90)[] || pr.coderefout
```

in the recursive part has type `varchar[]`.

This is because the array concatenation operator `||` removes the type modifier:

```
SELECT '{a,b,c}'::varchar(90)[] || 'd'::varchar(90) \gdesc

  Column  |        Type         
----------+---------------------
 ?column? | character varying[]
(1 row)
```

You's have to add an explicit cast to the result of the concatenation:

```
(chemin || pr.coderefout)::varchar(90)[]
```

To avoid annoyances like that, don't use type modifiers there. I'd just use `varchar` or shorter, but synonymous, `text`. You are not using the column in the final result anyway.

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful explanation, I understand something and it works, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to cast everything to text, by using `ARRAY[p.coderefout::text]` in the anchor query and `chemin::text || pr.coderefout` in the recursive query. There is no need to cast everything to an array

```
with recursive sousSujet(typerefin,coderefin,typerefout,coderefout,type,profondeur,chemin, boucle) as (

    SELECT p.typerefin, p.coderefin, p.typerefout, p.coderefout, p.type, 1,
           ARRAY[p.coderefout::text], false  
    FROM relation p
    WHERE p.coderefin='2019094070' and p.typerefin='PROJET'

    union all 

    SELECT p.typerefin, p.coderefin, pr.typerefout, pr.coderefout, p.type ,pr.profondeur+1,
           chemin::text|| pr.coderefout,
           pr.coderefout = ANY(pr.chemin)
    FROM relation p
      join sousSujet pr 
        on p.coderefin = pr.coderefout 
       AND NOT pr.boucle 
       and pr.profondeur < 10
)
SELECT typerefin,coderefin,typerefout,coderefout,type,profondeur
FROM sousSujet 
order by coderefout limit 20
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, its basicaly the cleanest query that I wanted to reach.

and finaly the cleanest thing I could do is to cast theses two elements
`
- ARRAY[p.coderefout]::varchar(90)[]
- (chemin|| pr.coderefout)::varchar(90)[]
`
"::text" don't work but as you said I don't need to cast other. thanks you