# Postgres error: recursive query "cte" column 4 has type character varying(32)[] in non-recursive term but type character varying[] overall

Tags: arrays, postgresql, recursion, common-table-expression

I'm trying to migrate an oracle query to Postgres:

```
SELECT  /*+ materialize */ distinct   r.empid, r.mgr_id, CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF leafs
         FROM (Select * from empid_reports_to_mgrid WHERE  sysdate BETWEEN eff_date AND eff_date_end) r
   CONNECT BY PRIOR r.mgr_id = r.empid
   START WITH r.empid IN (SELECT distinct empid
                           FROM employee
                          WHERE event_oid ='345345'  AND F_HISTORICAL=0 and F_ELIGIBLE=1);
```

I arrived at this solution:

```
       ( with recursive cte ( empid, mgr_id,level, visited, root_id) AS 
    (
      select  empid::varchar ,
             mgr_id::varchar,
             1 as level, 
             array[empid]::varchar[] as visited, 
             empid::varchar as root_id
      from   (Select * from empid_reports_to_mgrid WHERE  now() BETWEEN eff_date AND eff_date_end
      where empid IN (SELECT distinct empid
                               FROM employee
                              WHERE event_oid ='345345' AND F_HISTORICAL=0 and F_ELIGIBLE=1) ) e 
  union all
  select c.empid::varchar,
         c.mgr_id::varchar,
         p.level + 1, 
         (p.visited::varchar[] ||c.empid::varchar[]), 
         p.root_id::varchar
  from (Select * from empid_reports_to_mgrid WHERE  now() BETWEEN eff_date AND eff_date_end) c
   join cte p on p.mgr_id= c.empid
  where c.empid <> all(p.visited)
)
SELECT e.*, 
       not exists (select * from cte p where p.mgr_id = e.empid) as leafs
FROM cte e);
```

The columns empid and mgr_id are of data type varchar(32).

When I run this query, I'm getting the below error:

```
SQL Error [42804]: ERROR: recursive query "cte" column 4 has type character varying(32)[] in non-recursive term but type character varying[] overall
  Hint: Cast the output of the non-recursive term to the correct type.
```

The type casts that are present have been added after looking at the below post which suggests to type cast the recursive columns to get rid of the error but it dint work:
[Postgres CTE : type character varying(255)[] in non-recursive term but type character varying[] overall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488282/postgres-cte-type-character-varying255-in-non-recursive-term-but-type-char?rq=1)

How do we migrate CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF to postgres? Please help!

Also, what are the recursive columns in this case?

If I'm typecasting to text and text[] instead of varchar and varchar[], I'm getting the below error:
malformed array literal: "21466694N" Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

Comment: Try casting to `text` and `text[]`.

Comment: Getting this error after changing all varchars to text: malformed array literal: "21466694N"
  Detail: Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

Comment: `c.empid::text[]` cannot work. Use `c.empid::text`.